# Does react native support development for below android 5.0 apps

Tags: react-native

I was developing app for 4.2.2 but unable to run adb reverse command as the react documentation says it wont suport below 5.0. Hence I am unable to produce apk

Using adb reverse 
Note that this option is available on devices running android 5.0+ (API 21).
Have your device connected via USB with debugging enabled (see paragraph above on how to enable USB debugging on your device).

Link: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.18/docs/running-on-device-android.html#content

Comment: You can still use the option `Configure your app to connect to the local dev server via Wi-Fi` down below the docs, I am using it with my Android 4.4